# Why does this clojure hello world throw a NullPointerException?

Tags: clojure

This is my very first program:

```
(println "hello, what is your name?")
(let [myname (read-line)]
  ((println (str "hello " myname))))
```

It kinda works:

```
hello, what is your name?
Joel
hello Joel
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException, compiling:(/home/joel/workspace/coolstuff/clojure/hello.clj:1:38)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7142)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7086)
    at clojure.main$load_script.invoke(main.clj:274)
    at clojure.main$script_opt.invoke(main.clj:336)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:420)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:379)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:154)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at user$eval3.invoke(hello.clj:3)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6703)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7130)
    ... 9 more
```

Why does it throw an exception?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
((println (str "hello " myname)))
```

...is running the thing *returned by println* as a function.

println doesn't return anything. Hence, it returns null. Hence, running its return value as a function throws a NullPointerException.

Take out the extra parenthesis:

```
(println (str "hello " myname))
```